# Qt5 Change Softlink of Currently Running Executable

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, symlink

I created 2 simple Qt5.5 test apps on Linux, "red" and "green". I setup an initial soft link in the current directory that looks like this:

```
gui -> red
```

I want to be able to launch the gui app at any time and have it switch the softlink to the other 'color' app. So when I run gui and it points to red, the next time I run gui it will point to green.

The red app code to do this looks like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // Get the current path
    QString cwd = QDir::currentPath();
    qDebug() << cwd + "/green";
    bool success = QFile::link(cwd + "/green",cwd + "/gui");
    qDebug() << "Was successful: " << success;
}
```

The green app code to do this looks like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // Get the current path
    QString cwd = QDir::currentPath();
    qDebug() << cwd + "/red";
    bool success = QFile::link(cwd + "/red",cwd + "/gui");
    qDebug() << "Was successful: " << success;
}
```

The problem is that the "success" boolean always fails. I guess I cannot change the soft link of a currently running process. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove link before recreating it:

> This function will not overwrite an already existing entity in the
>   file system; in this case, link() will return false and set error() to
>   return RenameError.

[QFile::link()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#link).